# Python Insert value from list into a URL

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to add a iterate through a list with an API call. With each iteration, i want the current entry to insert its value into the URL. I've tried using the `.format()` method, but doesn't seem to work. The URl calls but fails. It should look like this: /mailMessages/7928?include. When I print(idents) i get

```
[Running] python "....testoid.py"
[['17685']]
```

Code:

```
for ident in idents:
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    r = http.request('GET', 'https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/mailbox/mailMessages/{0}?include_body=1&api_token=TOKEN'.format(ident))
    datas = list()
    mails = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
    datas.append(mails)
```

Could somebody point me in the right direction here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: sorry, updated the question to be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help. You need to have the `'datas'` list outside the for loop.

```
datas = list()
for ident in idents:
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    r = http.request('GET', 'https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/mailbox/mailMessages/{0}?include_body=1&api_token=TOKEN'.format(ident))
    mails = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
    datas.append(mails)
```

Comment: Thank you rakesh. I realized after doing this that it is a problem with the list. When i print the list, i get the format ['18284'] and that's what is being inserted into the URL, what should be inserted is just 18284.